# FR4, 1 oz. copper, PCB trace width for 48V/8A, pulsed (8 ms pulse length, up to 20Hz)?

Tags: pcb-design, solenoid, trace

I would like to determine suitable trace width for the pulses shown.
Other details: The application is to pulse a solenoid; board size is 100mm x 100mm. An LM317 charges a 1000uF cap and the cap is discharged into the solenoid using a low side MOSFET. I have it working nicely on perf board. I've used trace width calculators but I am not sure how to address pulses. The average current through the trace is less than 500mA. The solenoid draws about 9W average (limited by the LM317).
**edit: I acknowledge the frequency shown on the plot is 10Hz but I would like to design for up to 20Hz; also the MOSFET and diodes are just stand-ins for simulating; please don't scrutinize them.*
[image].

Answer (score 1):

Check the RMS value of your current waveform (rms, not average!). With 10 Hz and above that seems like a reasonable value to design the trace width from.

Then decide what temperature rise of your trace in comparison to ambient you want to allow and choose the trace width accordingly after a table like this one:
[image]

Comment: Do these values apply to internal layers as well?

Comment: Actually this table does not tell, but it is very likely for outer layers. Inner layers have a derating, depending on which literature you check between 5% and 50%...

Comment: @jusaca That table looks suspect to me. Look at the 0.2" width line, 2oz copper, current handling is less for 20C than 10C, then rises for 30C, and that's just the first line I checked!

Comment: Ha, you are right, the value for 2oz, 20°C, 0.2 witdh does not make sense. On further inspection it seems to me to be the only mistake I can spot, but it certainly decreases confidence.

Comment: @Neil_UK The table above is entirely copied from IPC-2221 - the values are the same. IPC should have done the same mistake maybe?

Comment: @RohatKılıç  it's probably a typo for a handwritten  '17', which number would interpolate those around it, I always write my 7s crossed the european way, to distinguish them from 1s with a long top tick

Comment: Ok based on average RMS amps of 1.5, I put down 60mil traces according to this tool : https://www.digikey.com/en/resources/conversion-calculators/conversion-calculator-pcb-trace-width

Comment: FYI, an improved standard is IPC-2152, which includes inner layers, and the effect of inner planes. For example: https://www.smps.us/pcb-calculator.html